# Angular Material Dialog - fixed position element height getting cut off at random point

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I need to add an element inside of an Angular Material dialog that has it's own height and will be unaffected by the dialog (imagine a custom dropdown). Whenever I do this, the dialog gets chopped off at the bottom, but very oddly - not directly at the bottom of the dialog. It's allowed to go about 20px beyond the bottom, and then gets randomly cut off.

Code pen here: http://codepen.io/kathk1/pen/woQWRZ

```
.rectangle {
  background: red;
  height: 900px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

If you launch that dialog, the red rectangle which is the fixed element in this case should be 900px tall, but it isn't allowed to get that tall.

[image: static image of the rectangle issue here]

What is making it do this and/or how do I get it to stop doing it? I'm stumped.

Sorry editing for clarity: I **want** the red rectangle to extend to its full 900px **beyond** the dialog. I do not want the dialog to scroll.

Comment: Hmm so the rectangle to extend to its fullest height and width without effecting the dialog dimensions ? This means it will overlay the dialog contents right?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make the red rectangle inside of the white square?

If so, change the property, `position:fixed;` to `position: relative;`, the white square, will gain a vertical scroll.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post for clarity. I want the rectangle to be it's full 900px tall and extend over and past the dialog. Imagine a really long custom dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

START UPDATE 1

based on your edit, `md-dialog` hides content that `overflow`. You will need to override this behavior to show the entire rectangle. With your existing css,add this to show the rectangle.

```
md-dialog.md-default-theme
{  
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

[image]

END UPDATE 1

---

You can create an exterior `div`,set a to fixed height of choice and let the contents inside overflow and scroll.

css

```
.wrapOne{     
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:30px;
}
.rectangle {
    background: red;
    height: 900px;  
    width:200px;
}
```

template

```
    '<md-dialog aria-label="Sample Dialog">' +
    '<md-content>'+
    '<div class="wrapOne"><div class="rectangle">TESTING------TESTING------TESTING------TESTING------TESTING------</div></div>'+
    '    <md-list>'+
    '      <md-item ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">'+
    '       <p>{{item}}</p>' +
    '      </md-item>'+
    '    </md-list>'+
    '  </md-content>' +
    '  <div class="md-actions">' +
    '    <md-button ng-click="ctrl.closeDialog()">' +
    '      Close Greeting' +
    '    </md-button>' +
    ' ' +
    '</md-dialog>',
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post for clarity. I want the rectangle to be it's full 900px tall and extend over and past the dialog. Imagine a really long custom dropdown.

Comment: How interesting. That does work! Thank you so much. I guess I missed that because of how it was letting it hang off a little. Wonder why that was.

Comment: @kathkroll nice to know that worked out.Please mark the answer as completed to help other on the way. Happy coding.